# Applying Animated Shadow to Bootstrap 4 Card

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I've been trying to figure out how I can apply an animated shadow to a Bootstrap 4 Card. Currently, I have some Cards set out like this:

[Pic of Bootstrap Card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDySt.png)

The goal is to apply an animated shadow around the boxlike in this video. I've attached a pic too but the vid shows the animation:

(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1EAtn4B-76g)

[Pic of Box with Border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpght.png)

The actual code for the animated box in the Youtube example is:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #000;
}

.shadow {
    position: relative;
    margin: 200px auto 0;
    width: 400px;
    height: 250px;
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, #000, #262626);
}

.shadow:before,
.shadow:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -2px;
    left: -2px;
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, #fb0094, #0000ff, #00ff00, #ffff00, #ff0000, #fb0094, #0000ff, #00ff00, #ffff00, #ff0000);
    background-size: 400%;
    width: calc(100% + 4px);
    height: calc(100% + 4px);
    z-index: -1;
    animation: animate 20s linear infinite;
}

.shadow:after {
    filter: blur(10px);
}

@keyframes animate {
    0% {
        background-position: 0 0;
    }
    50% {
        background-position: 300% 0;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 0 0;
    }
}
```

I am a complete novice at Bootstrap and CSS. I've tried everything to add this to the card but I can't work it out at all. I can apply the rainbow type gradient above the card, but as soon as I change the z-index to -1 it seems to disappear completely.

[Photo of the Gradient before applying Z-Index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aX6D9.png)

I would be super grateful for any advice/guidance on how I could apply an animated glow around Bootstrap 4 Cards! :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the way, you can do it.

`margin-top: 5rem;` and `margin-left: 5rem;` is just for `styling purpose` so you know the border is applied in all positions.

```css
.shadow {
    /* JUST FOR STYLING */
    margin-left: 5rem;
    margin-top: 5rem;
    /* JUST FOR STYLING */
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, #000, #262626);
}

.shadow:before,
.shadow:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -2px;
    left: -2px;
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, #fb0094, #0000ff, #00ff00, #ffff00, #ff0000, #fb0094, #0000ff, #00ff00, #ffff00, #ff0000);
    background-size: 400%;
    width: calc(100% + 4px);
    height: calc(100% + 4px);
    z-index: -1;
    animation: animate 20s linear infinite;
}

.shadow:after {
    filter: blur(10px);
}

@keyframes animate {
    0% {
        background-position: 0 0;
    }
    50% {
        background-position: 300% 0;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 0 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="card shadow" style="width: 18rem;">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/1920/1080" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
    <div class="card-body bg-light">
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hey! I tried running with your version (and even created a new project to make sure nothing in my existing one was conflicting with it) - I seem to get a black shadow but it's not colored or animated. Yours gives me this so not sure if I'm doing something wrong here! - https://imgur.com/a/Bu1XPAa Its almost as if as soon as I apply the class to a card it doesn't work. I don't have a strong enough knowledge of bootstrap or css to figure out why.

Comment: brother you can run code snippet in StackOverflow and its works correctly, see in snippet

Comment: Thanks - yes it works great - turns out it is something in my code that's stopping it working. I have a CSS script that applies a gradient to the background of the whole page. If I remove that, works fine. Soon as I add it, it kicks the box glow out. Not sure why, back to researching! Thanks for all the help.